# Save file with double quote

Tags: c#, encoding

I have this code to write to a file, it works perfect but I have a case where a client who recorded double quote at the beginning and end of a record.
I can understand that by encoding replace the accents, but I do not like me can happen.

EDIT ini.

```
string recno = string.empty;

recno = "123;1548;1567;10-10-01";
```

EDIT end.

```
using (FileStream fsRes = new FileStream(fileSts, FileMode.Append))
{
   using (TextWriter twRes = new StreamWriter(fsRes, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
   {
      twRes.WriteLine(recno);
   }
}
```

Data on file:

Normal behavior:

```
123;1548;1567;10-10-01
```

On the client with the problem:

```
"123;1548;1567;10-10-01"
```

---

Edit:
I do not know how to explain, but in the same way that the problem started, so I finish. 
So, sorry but do not know what happened, just hopefully not happen again.

The project I did not change, and the code is that I used as example.

Thank you all for the answers.

@Bobby, I'll see then implement the code that you put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a problem with the TextWriter?

```
using (StreamWriter strm = new StreamWriter(fileSts, true, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))) {
    strm.WriteLine(recno);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is just a case of needing to trim double quotes from either end of the string:

```
recno = recno.Trim('\"');
```

If that's not the case, please give more information. I can't see how this is really related to files or encodings.

Comment: The problem is that I have no double quotation mark in the recording into a text file. 
The code is that that step as an example, no changes.

Comment: I'm afraid I find that hard to believe. StreamWriter doesn't magically insert quotes.

Comment: I know, for that reason that this is not happening.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to replace all quotes (including the ones that might appear in the middle of the text) you could use:

```
string s = recno.Replace("\"","");
```